# Is there any identified policy China is doing to successfully reduce COVID-19 the other countries aren't using?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, health-policy

Over the last days (beginning of March 2020), active cases of COVID-19 from China have dropped at a rate of 1,000-2,000 per day. China is the only country which seems able to reduce the amount of active cases, assuming the information which is coming from China is true.

Is there any identified policy China is doing to successfully reduce COVID-19, that other countries aren't using?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I learned a lot researching your question and even without acceptance it was well worth the education.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ?

Comment: FYI: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/are-there-other-trackers-indexes-of-governments-response-to-covid-19-beside-ox

Answer (score 2):

## To Mask or not To Mask that is the question

One thing China did early on was wearing face masks to protect others. They are still doing it today even though there has been [no deaths for 10 days](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/04/no-covid-19-deaths-10-days-chinas-wuhan-200425154631443.html) and most new cases (counted in dozens and not 10s of thousands like USA today) are [imported rather than community spread](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2020-04-24/china-reports-12-new-coronavirus-cases-no-new-deaths). This picture from a couple days ago:

[image: coronavirus china face masks.png]

Source: https://www.upi.com/Top_News/World-News/2020/04/25/Global-coronavirus-death-toll-hits-200000-China-reports-10-days-of-no-deaths/8211587816006/?ur3=1

However Delaware's Governor John Carney just ordered today all citizens to wear masks starting this coming Tuesday (April 28, 2020):

- [New order requires Delaware residents to wear face coverings](https://www.mrt.com/news/article/New-order-requires-Delaware-residents-to-wear-15226421.php)

So slowly but surely America is starting to do some of the things that China has done.

Comment: So only a mask, no face mask shield (plastic)

Comment: @America face masks, face shields and/or goggles are common hospital covid wards these days. I'd like to see them seal those wards off from rest of hospital like they did in China. That said there have been outbreaks in BC and Alberta meat processing plants and I'd like to see our governments mandate face shields (and masks of course) in those plants which are refrigerated with low fresh air replacement to save money on new air refrigeration.